# How to calculate running total of the subtotal

Tags: python, while-loop, cumulative-sum, subtotal

So I need to calculate a running total of both "sub_total" so both of these prices are added together and display in the "overall_total" variable. Currently, the output is showing $20.00 instead of $310.00. I am not sure how to make it add the price of both purchases together, instead of adding the last purchase together. Thank you and I'll appreciate any help or tips.[image: Current Output]

```
import custom

def main():
    each_item = True
    total = 0
    i = 0
    purchase = int(input('How many different items are being purchased? '))
    while each_item is True:
        i = i + 1
        desc = input('Enter description of item ' +str(i)+ ' ')
        part = int(input('Enter part number of item ' +str(i)+ ' '))
        price = int(input('Enter price of item ' +str(i)+ ' '))
        quant = int(input('Enter the quantity for item ' +str(i)+ ' '))
        sub_total = custom.subtotal(desc,part,price,quant)
        overall_total = sub_total + sub_total
        print(f'Item: {desc}, Part Number: {part}, subtotal: ${sub_total:.2f}\n')
        if i == purchase:
            print(f'Your total is: ${overall_total:.2f}')
            break
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do using a "for loop".

```
def main():
    overall_total = 0
    purchase = int(input('How many different items are being purchased? '))

    for i in range(1, purchase+1):
        desc = input('Enter description of item ' +str(i)+ ' ')
        part = int(input('Enter part number of item ' +str(i)+ ' '))
        price = int(input('Enter price of item ' +str(i)+ ' '))
        quant = int(input('Enter the quantity for item ' +str(i)+ ' '))
        sub_total = price*quant
        overall_total = overall_total + sub_total
        print(f'Item: {desc}, Part Number: {part}, subtotal: ${sub_total:.2f}\n')

    print(f"Your total is ${overall_total}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

so since you edited ur question i will also edit my answer.
If you loop through the while loop python will forget the previous value of subtotal to work around that you could create an array and store the total at the end of your loop (before the value gets reassigned by the next loop).

```
 subTotalValues = []
 while each_item is True:
    i = i + 1
    desc = input('Enter description of item ' +str(i)+ ' ')
    part = int(input('Enter part number of item ' +str(i)+ ' '))
    price = int(input('Enter price of item ' +str(i)+ ' '))
    quant = int(input('Enter the quantity for item ' +str(i)+ ' '))
    sub_total = custom.subtotal(desc,part,price,quant)
    subTotalValues.append(sub_total)
   print(f'Item{desc},PartNumber{part},subtotal:${sub_total:.2f}\n')
    if i == purchase:
        overall_total = subTotalValues[0] + subTotalValues[1]
        print(f'Your total is: ${overall_total:.2f}')
        break
```

Comment: Hello! Sorry about that, I had figured something else out and then realized I had a new problem lol. Your code ran perfectly for me so thank you! Do you mind just explaining a bit to me about what [] and ".append" means? I have not used those before and would help to have a little bit of context for my pseudocode. Thank you again!

Comment: sure thing, do you mind giving me your discord? as it is easier for me to explain it on discord.